# Why did I fail following review audit?

Tags: discussion, review-audits

The review audit is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/10483130).

[image]

I tapped EDIT. Why did I fail? It is completely well written sql query. It is not formatted, this is why I choise EDIT. Now I need to wait 7 days. It is not spam, it is quite correct answer.

Comment: At a glance, the question asked "*Just need someone to tell me if this statement has the proper syntax or not; i cannot get it to work properly.*" whereas the answer provided didn't actually *answer* the question. Maybe I'm missing something - my SQL knowledge is weak.

Comment: You weren't review banned for this specific audit failure, it was a combination of previous failed audits.  As far as this post goes, I would have commented asking the author to clarify how this query answered the question.

Comment: Ok, I got it. The answer could be correct, but not in this question. I was paying attention about spam, but sometimes answer that seems to be good also may be an audit. Ok, thanks guys.

Comment: There were three accepted "not an answer" flags, one "very low quality" flag, and one spam flag on that answer. Whole bunch of people thought it was trash or nonsense, and there must be some context here.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That answer, as others have pointed out, is pretty weak. The OP asked "if this statement has the proper syntax or not," but the "answer" doesn't attempt to answer that question. Instead, it is a query that uses totally different names for the table and columns. So, it's a pretty bad answer and not really fixable by a reviewer making edits.

That said, I can't recall why I deleted that answer. Ordinarily, a bad post like this should just be down voted, not deleted. But as Brad Larson said in the comments, there must have been some context. This answer drew a lot of flags, even though it only existed for about 90 seconds. I can't say for sure at this point, but if I recall correctly, the author was making a lot of edits during the grace period, some of which had absolutely nothing to do with the question.

So, is it a good answer? No, definitely not. Is it a good audit? No, it's not.

Comment: *"So, is it a good answer? No, definitely not"* - upvote for your answer, but the heart of the matter hear IMO is that the answer cannot become good, so editing it was the wrong choice. I'd say yes a good audit on that basis, it did its job.

Answer (score 2):

That is a weak answer and you could not have edited into proper shape without spending at least as much or more effort then the answerer did. Edits of this magnitude are generally discouraged and such posts are to be deleted.