# Can a suggestion be an answer or does it need to be a comment?

Tags: discussion, comments, disputed-review-audits, not-an-answer, late-answers

I recently failed the following review audit in the Late Answers queue:
https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/15595844

**Question title:**

> git commit signing failed: secret key not available

**Answer:**

> Maybe you need to clone your own repository where you have rights. I had this issue when I cloned the repository of another person.

The way I saw it was that someone asked a question about git commit signing and someone answered by suggesting they clone their own repository. I don't have much experience using git, so I don't know if this suggestion would actually solve the problem. I do know that the answer is git related, and so to me it looks like a possible solution.

Once I failed the audit, I saw that the answer had been downvoted and had the following comment:

> This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient reputation you will be able to comment on any post; instead, provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker. - From Review

The answer may be wrong, yet that would be a reason to downvote, not flag.
Related: [Bad Late Answer Audits?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/346115/bad-late-answer-audits?cb=1)

I don't think this is a situation where asking the asker for clarification was required. The answerer seemed to have a valid suggestion for the stated problem. You are not required to ask in comments, "Does this solution solve your problem?" before writing it up in an answer. And a solution may not work for the original asker, yet it may help someone else in the future who has the same problem. Besides, if this is really a late answer, asking for clarification at this point most likely will not get any response anyway.

The only possible problem I see with this answer is that the word "maybe" was used, which makes it sound like a comment. If it would be phrased as "Try cloning your own repository where you have rights", maybe it would be better, yet the actual answer doesn't change, so I didn't feel an edit was necessary.

Should I have edited the answer to remove the word "maybe", so it sounds more like an answer?

Is this answer really bad and should I have flagged it? Is this really only a comment and not an answer?

Should I have skipped this review since it is for a topic I am not too familiar with?

If I correctly failed the audit, I'm okay with that. I just want to know how to deal with similar answers in the future.

---

#### Update:

It seems like everyone is in agreement that while the answer may be a poor answer, it still should not be considered "not-an-answer".

The answer has now been undeleted and the comment saying it is not an answer has been removed.

Since it seems like I did nothing wrong in selecting "No Action Needed" in the review queue, can the failed audit now be removed from my review history?

Comment: In some queues, attempting to edit when viewing an audit automatically makes you fail: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274804/why-does-just-clicking-edit-fail-review-audit and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/311964/why-did-i-fail-following-review-audit as examples.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If a question doesn't contain enough information for you to post an answer, the solution is not to post an answer to a question that is lacking in details, or to which the validity of cannot be verified, but rather to improve the question such that it can be answers with an objectively correct answer.

That, along with the fact that the answer is *severely* lacking in details about the solution that it isn't even sure is appropriate, certainly makes it a low quality answer.

Now, having determined that the answer is low quality, and that the user would have been better served improving the question such that it could be answered definitively, that doesn't make the answer "Not An Answer".  While the answer is *bad*, and certainly merits a downvote in my eyes, it is *an attempt to answer the question*, and not seeking clarification (it's simply making it clear that clarification is needed).  Given this, it was inappropriate to delete the answer on the grounds that it isn't an answer.

> Should I have edited the answer to remove the word "maybe", so it sounds more like an answer?

To be honest, I still see the answer is a very poor answer even if this change were to be made.  And honestly, the fact that the author doesn't actually know if this is an appropriate approach is something I'd rather want to know as a reader.  The answer really needs more help than I expect you're capable of giving it in an edit, so I personally wouldn't recommend it.

> Should I have skipped this review since it is for a topic I am not too familiar with?

One's technical knowledge of the material at hand isn't really necessary here, so I don't see a reason to skip it on those grounds.  You may not feel comfortable enough to go to the question and downvote it (despite suspecting that it's a bad answer) for this reason, but you don't need technical expertise to judge if it merits deletion.

Comment: So was I okay in selecting "No Action Needed" and is this indeed a bad audit?

Comment: @TotZam Yes, the post was incorrectly deleted.

Comment: Is there a way then to remove a failed audit from my review history?

Comment: @TotZam Unless you actually get review banned in the next few weeks, there's no reason to bother.  They're only ever considered for a short period of time.

Comment: I did get review banned because of this, but that ban has already passed. The reason I would want it removed is because if I now review even one thing incorrectly, I will right away be banned again and for a longer time, since it wouldn't be the first audit I failed. If failed audit history is really only ever considered for a short period of time, I wouldn't have been banned now for just failing a single audit.

Answer (score 10):

That was an attempt at answering the question and did not have any severe content or formatting problems. It was deleted incorrectly through review. Such content should be reviewed as "Looks OK" / "No action needed" (depending on the queue).

If a user thinks that such content is not useful, they should downvote it. If they have delete votes and the post is eligible and they feel like delete voting, then that would be appropriate.

I have flagged the deleted answer with the following flag:

> This was incorrectly deleted by review and is being used as a review audit that sensible users are failing (at least one that I know of). I don't mind it being deleted, it just shouldn't be a review audit because it is an attempt at answering the question.

### [You're doing it wrong: A plea for sanity in the Low Quality Posts queue](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287563/youre-doing-it-wrong-a-plea-for-sanity-in-the-low-quality-posts-queue)

Comment: Reading over the link, I appreciate your comment. I deleted mine as I misunderstood not realising it had been clocked. The point still stands that it is a terrible answer IMO and such an answer would warrant a down vote. Had I come across it in review that's what I would have done. I wouldn't have flagged as NAA.

Comment: To put a spin on it, does the post actually attempt to answer the question? It does we can agree on that and flagging it as NAA would be wrong. Does it help anyone on the _how_? It doesn't. If it doesn't have a _how_ should it be on the site? A lot of people jump on the "SO is meant to be an encyclopaedia of all knowledge" bandwagon. Forgive me but this answer is far from that. Should it not then be removed. Down voting it makes sense but leaving it on the site doesn't. Or am I being cruel? I'd have to go back to Google and look elsewhere on _how_ to apply that answer.

Comment: Whether or not something should be on the site is irrelevant with regards to flagging and reviewing. The question you should be asking yourself when flagging or reviewing is "Does this fit the criteria for a standard flag?" If the answer is no, it should not be flagged, nor recommended for deletion through review. Once you get to 20k rep you get the privilege of being able to cast delete votes on answers. At that point you can start delete voting answers that you think should not be on the site. I definitely agree with it being deleted, I just don't agree with _how_ it was deleted. @Bugs

Comment: Makes sense @TinyGiant thanks for clearing it up.